# ios:How to persist object value in viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am having one view controller WebViewController and second is Settings. On tap of button i am adding Settings view controller as subview of webviewcontroller.

```
menusettings=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SET"];
[menusettings.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 700,600)];
[self.view addSubview:menusettings.view];
```

I have Webview Object in the 
Webview controller

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *wrae_one;
```

and i am loading data in webview but when i cal function from Settings controller then the value self.wrae_one becoming null. Means when i add setting view controller as subview in webview controller then obejet of webview become null. Is there any way to main it value. In settings i am using this code for calling the function

```
self.home_webview=[[PRGVwebViewController alloc]init];
[self.home_webview loadWebviewController]
```

Comment: Please give some suggesstions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that PRGVwebViewController is the class from which the settingsviewcontroller is instantiated. So why do you re alloc the class? Doing this you are creating a new controller, but when you dismiss the settingsviewcontroller, you are seeing the first one.
You have to create a reference to the previous controller.

Maybe, the best way is to instantiate the WebViewController as a sharedIstance (singleton), so you can access to it (and only it) wherever you want.

This can be helpful: http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/12/19/fundamental-ios-design-patterns-sharedinstance-singleton-objective-c/

Comment: I have read somewhere if any viewcontroller is not visible then ARC will deallocate the object of that viewcontroller is it true??

Comment: in context of my question can you pleas tell me how can i create shared instance of the PRGVWebViewcontroller

Comment: ARC ('Automatic Reference Counting') will dealloc objects when there are not  the object reference links. For you problem, you have to use the reference to the principal view controller. Instead alloc the VC normally, you will use it calling the method [[YOUR-VC SharedInstance]MethodName];